# DIferencia entre usar google map mediante su API y copiar el embed de su página web

Tags: google-maps

He visto que algunos implementan google maps con una API KEY.Sin embargo,eligiendo una coordenada desde la página web de google maps y copiando el embeb puedo ponerlo facilmente en una página web.Entonces que diferencias hay entre hacerlo de las dos maneras.En que casos se usaría el primer método?

Answer (score 0):

Son dos servicios diferentes:
La API está desarrollada para la implementación con proyectos que necesiten un servicio de mapas, como por ejemplo: cálculos de distancia entre dos puntos, rutas, geolocalizar unas coordenadas, entre muchas posibilidades más que podrás conocer directamente en su web [Google Maps](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/products/?hl=es&sign=0). Cabe resaltar que por el uso de la API pueden cobrarte en caso de pasar los primeros 200USD que te regalan por mes.

Con el Embed solo puedes compartir una ubicación estática en html sin mas interacción por parte de los usuarios o tuya.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay 2 variantes:

1.- Costos

El api de google maps no es gratis.
Usando embed el costo de la peticion para generar el embed es de 7 peticiones por 1 dolar (Un ejemplo)

Usando el api con javascript cada peticion cuesta 1 dolar.
En resumen, las peticion por javascript son mas caras que las del embed

2.- Funcionalidades

El embed es muy limitado, puedes generar markers (pines), pero no le puedes dar eventos propios.

En cambio con el javascript puedes generar un evento cuando seleccionas un pin para abrir un tooltip o un modal o generar cierta accion.

En javascript puedes generar eventos para zoom, para streetview, agregar la capa de trafico, generar polylines, crear elementos de html propios dentro del mapa, generar geocercas, etc..
En resumen, trae mas funcionalidades aunque mas dificil de implementar javascript que el embed.

Nota. Las 2 requieren un API KEY

Embed
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Javascript
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Parece que el embed que hace referencia no es el del API sino el de Google Maps, por su comentario de: "Sin embargo,eligiendo una coordenada desde **la página web de google maps** y copiando el embeb puedo ponerlo facilmente en una página web".